# Filtering out DNA repeats with vcftools

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to filter out repeats from DNA sequence reads. For this, I have:

- **grw_vcf_filtered_2.vcf** as the input file,
- **grw_repeatmasker_runner_combined.bed** with the repeat positions I want to filter out
- **grw_repeats_removed.vcf** as the output file I will generate.

However I keep getting the error: `grw_repeats_removed.vcf not such file or directory` after 4 minutes running.

Here is my code:

```
module load bioinfo-tools vcftools

cd $SNIC_TMP #making temporary file 

cp /proj/snic2020-2-25/nobackup/violeta/grw_vcf_filtered_2.vcf /proj/snic2020-2-25/nobackup/violeta/grw_repeatmasker_runner_combined.bed ./

vcftools --vcf grw_vcf_filtered_2.vcf --out grw_repeats_removed.vcf --exclude-positions grw_repeatmasker_runner_combined.bed

#copy from current location -temporary file- to my directory 

cp ./grw_repeats_removed.vcf /proj/snic2020-2-25/nobackup/violeta/
```

Comment: Is there any other message? Who is giving the error? The `vcftools` or the `cp`?

Comment: I think it is vcftools, it says: Run Time = 47.00 seconds
cp: cannot stat ‘./grw_repeats_removed.vcf’: No such file or directory
remove_repeats.err (END)client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

Comment: It is clearly the `cp`. You have the "cp" header in the error line. In that case, check which files is vcftools generating.

Answer (score 1):

vcftools is deprecated;

use bcftools

use option

```
-T, --targets-file [^]FILE        Similar to -R but streams rather than index-jumps. Exclude regions with "^" prefix
```

invoke:

```
bcftools view -O v -o grw_repeats_removed.vcf --targets-file ^grw_repeatmasker_runner_combined.bed grw_vcf_filtered_2.vcf
```